# WordPress - Check if user is logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

I am fairly new to WordPress. On my homepage I have a navigation bar which I only want to show to people who are logged in as users.

In my `header.php` the function `is_logged_in` doesn't seem to work.

I want to place a condition in my `header.php` file to check if the user has logged in (and then display the navigation).

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: have you tried is_user_logged_in() function?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

Comment: @BhumiShah "On my header.php the function is_logged_in does not seem to work."

Comment: is_logged_in is a pluggable function and as such, does not work directly. You need to hook it somewhere for it to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WordPress - Check if user is logged in from external PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369393/wordpress-check-if-user-is-logged-in-from-external-php-file)

Answer (score 92):

Use the `is_user_logged_in` function:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   // your code for logged in user 
} else {
   // your code for logged out user 
}
```

Comment: "On my header.php the function is_logged_in does not seem to work."

Comment: is_user_logged_in is working fine in header.php file.i have checked that

Comment: is_user_logged_in works everywhere without any issue even you can use it on external pages as well but you need to include wp-load.php in your file

Comment: @Hobo The question says that `is_logged_in` isn't working, not `is_user_logged_in`.

Comment: then provide your function so we can check,why its not working? because it's not a core function of wordpress

Comment: For anyone who finds this Q&A: Yes, the OP should have been using `is_user_logged_in`, as there is no `is_logged_in`. And the OP was asking about using this in _header.php_. If you have a plugin where the _pluginname.php_ file gets executed way before header.php, the `is_user_logged_in` function isn't available yet. A prior comment says "you need to include wp-load.php in your file". That's not correct. _wp-load_ defines ABSPATH early in the lifecycle - It's already been loaded. You want to `require ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php';`. The function is defined **there**.

Comment: @TonyG The `is_user_logged_in()` function does not exist in my case. Not sure what's going on, according to the documentation it is not deprecated.

Comment: @inf3rno - It's still in there. I'm guessing your `require` line is incorrect. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/6.4/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1162

Comment: @TonyG Not really, it does not exist before `init`.

Answer (score 6):

Example: Display different output depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

```
<?php

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

`get_current_user_id()` will return the current user id (an integer), or will return 0 if the user is not logged in.

```
if (get_current_user_id()) {
   // display navbar here
}
```

More details here [get_current_user_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/).

Comment: Correct and official answer.

Comment: `get_current_user_id()` always returns 0 in the early startup cycle when a plugin is first invoked through _pluginname.php_. The value is zero even for a logged-in user. However, as an answer to the OP question, this is correct in that at header.php, this function should return a correct value.

Answer (score 3):

Try following code that worked fine for me

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
```

Then, use following code to check whether user has logged in or not.

```
if ($current_user->ID == '') { 
    //show nothing to user
}
else { 
    //write code to show menu here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is from the lazy update data request of Chrome.
At the first time you go to homepage. Chrome request with empty data. Then you go to the login page and logged in. When you back home page Chrome lazy to update the cookie data request because this domain is the same with the first time you access.
**Solution**: 
Add parameter for home url. That helps Chrome realizes that this request need to update cookie to call to the server.

add at dashboard page

```
<?php 
$track = '?track='.uniqid();
?>
<a href="<?= get_home_url(). $track ?>"> <img src="/img/logo.svg"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and found that the login check function needs to fire within the **'template_redirect'** hook, e.g:

```
function add_login_redirect()
{

    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        wp_redirect(home_url('/wp-admin'));
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'add_login_redirect');
```

Answer (score 0):

A neat way to check if particular user **is online** is to check the `session_tokens` meta key from `usermeta` table. Place this function in your `functions.php` and check the returned value:

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('check_last_login_time')) {
    function check_last_login_time($user_id) {
        $login_time = NULL;
        //Get only 1 record from Database: parameter `true`
        $user_session_tokens = get_user_meta($user_id, "session_tokens", true); 
        if(is_array($user_session_tokens) && !empty($user_session_tokens)) {
            foreach($user_session_tokens as $key=>$val) {
                $login_time = $val["login"];
            }
        } 
        return $login_time;
    }
}
```

**Note**: if there is no `session_tokens` key, that means that user is not online (i.e. not logged-in), otherwise the variable returned by the function will contain `UNIX timestamp` of last successful login time.

Answer (score -1):

I think that.
When guest is launching page, but Admin is not logged in we don`t show something, for example the Chat.

```
add_action('init', 'chat_status');

function chat_status(){

    if( get_option('admin_logged') === 1) { echo "<style>.chat{display:block;}</style>";}
        else { echo "<style>.chat{display:none;}</style>";}

}



add_action('wp_login', function(){

    if( wp_get_current_user()->roles[0] == 'administrator' ) update_option('admin_logged', 1);
});


add_action('wp_logout', function(){
    if( wp_get_current_user()->roles[0] == 'administrator' ) update_option('admin_logged', 0);
});
```

Comment: This should be used if we develop a plugin using WP or maybe using function.php on theme. Why people down vote this kind of answer.. silly -_-

Comment: it'll reflect the changes for all users. if someone is logged in.