# PHP detect incoming jquery $.get() requests

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have in my Wordpress `header.php` file the following code to redirect users to my homepage if they're not logged in:

```
<?php if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
   wp_redirect( 'http://mydomain.com/');
   exit; 
} ?>
```

However this also prevents any `$.get()` calls from my other scripts to load contents. So my question is, is there something I can add to the above code to achieve the following:

```
if user is not logged in but request is not $.get()
    redirect them to home page
```

This way I can redirect not logged in users but still allow $.get() ajax calls to the pages.

Thanks

Comment: The thing is, if the user is not logged in and the request is context specific to the user then an Ajax request is not going to work.

Comment: Actually the request is not specific to the user, it's just a simple ajax request for some images or text from another page

Comment: If you try replacing "if(!is_user_logged_in()) {" with "if(false) {", do you get the required result?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946972/wordpress-check-if-user-is-logged-in)

Comment: @ChrisWalsh  I don't get it, if I use "if(false) {" then the necessary wordpress function "is_user_logged_in()" doesn't get called, which can't determine if user is logged in or not

Comment: Sorry, I meant, temporarily set the if statement to false just to check to see if your ajax request works.  I didn't mean as a permanent solution for normal Web usage + Ajax.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh just tried that and yea, my ajax does work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you swap `$.get` for `$.ajax`, you could send a request header to your script and test for that.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    headers: {"X-Origin-Header": "xhr"}
});
```

Then in your PHP

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
if ($headers["X-Origin-Header"] != "xhr" && !is_user_logged_in()) {
   wp_redirect( 'http://mydomain.com/');
   exit; 
}
```

Comment: I used $.get() because of the default async option. Does using $.ajax also provide an async option?

Comment: Yes, `$.ajax` is async by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below function

```
if (!function_exists('isAjax')) {

    function isAjax()
    {
        return (bool)(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strcasecmp($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'], 'XMLHttpRequest') === 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this along with the function isAjax(), "if (!is_user_logged_in() && !function_exists('isAjax')) {
", this allows the ajax request to pass through but doesn't filter the user anymore

Comment: You should write "if (!is_user_logged_in() && !isAjax()) {"