# WordPress - Check if user is logged in from external PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to check if WordPress user is logged in or not from an external PHP file and here is my code

```
<?php 
/*Load up wordpress externally*/
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', false );
define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON', true );
require('../../trading/wp-load.php');

if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
    $user =  wp_get_current_user();
    print_r($user);

}else{
    echo 'logged out';
}
```

?>

I always get 'logged out' message, even though the user is logged in.
Any idea how can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought your code was correct so I tested it (changing only the line "require('../../trading/wp-load.php');" to match my installation) and **it worked as expected** so code itself is correct and something else is wrong.

For WordPress (in a standard configuration) to know a user is logged it must receive a cookie. Can you add a

```
var_dump( $_COOKIE );
```

to your script and verify a cookie like ''wordpress_logged_in_ ...' is being received.

WordPress has hooks so user verification can be customised. Of course in a customised installation the above may not be true.

Comment: For my curiosity's sake what was the cause of the problem? The only things I could think of was a customised user verification or a mismatched cookies domain neither of which seem probable.

Comment: I put the script inside the WordPress directory and it worked :)

Comment: Of course, the path in the cookie did not match the path in the URL to your script and the browser did not send the cookie. Thanks for the info - I really like to understand why things don't work.

Answer (score 0):

When is this custom php file loaded? According to the [`Action Reference`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) - You need to wait until at least the [`init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) hook before the user is authenticated.

I would try:

```
add_action( 'init', 'FDI_logged_in' );
function FDI_logged_in(){
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        print_r( $user );
    } else {
        echo 'logged out';
    }
}
```