# How to make htaccess redirected download urls be only accessible by logged-in members on Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-masking

In general, the question is: How to mask external download links as internal links and to be only accessible by logged-in wp users at htaccess level or with PHP script? 
We have Perl based script at our external URL and its generating different download URLs. If you help how can we apply it on an external site we can do so.

We successfully redirect `www.ourwebsite.com/resources` to external download link by simple htaccess code:

```
Redirect 301 /resources https://external.com/direct-download-link1
```

However, if the URLs (www.ourwebsite.com/resources/download-1.html etc.) are scraped by WordPress members and share & paste into their browser address bars when they don't log in then the download links are still accessible. We want to prevent it. So how to disallow non-members from accessing download links directly?

Comment: On the download script, can't you just check for the WP user session and see if they're logged in? If not logged in show 404 error or whatever.

Comment: so how can i do that? can you show an example code for it?

Comment: Have you tried searching for it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946972/wordpress-check-if-user-is-logged-in

Answer (score 0):

If you can change where the redirect goes have it go to a PHP page where you may load WordPress and check the role of the user to make sure they are logged in.

```
require('../wp-load.php');  // modify to reflect where your PHP file is in relation to Wordpress
$roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;  // get current users role

if (!in_array('alloweduserrole',$roles)) {  // modify to match your roles that are allowed to download

    header('Location: http://www.ourwebsite.com/');
    exit;

}  // end of if user does not have the proper role
```

Comment: the problem is how to find that php script.

Comment: You would need to create it and/or change the current HTML page to PHP so you can do the checking before allowing the download.

Comment: do you know an example php script for that?

Comment: My answer contains what you need when modified as indicated in the comments.

Comment: should i add it into functions.php?

Comment: i have an idea: how can i take s2member plugin to take effect before htaccess redirection code?