# Wordpress: hide an element to Guests and show a div to Logged in users

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am setting up a new custom header for my website (editing the file header.php). I need to create a dynamic one, I have 2 divs:

Sign Out
Sign In

I need to show the first div only to Logged in Users and so hide the second one. Viceversa for the second div, I need the second one to display only if the user isn't logged into wordpress and hide the first one.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WordPress - Check if user is logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946972/wordpress-check-if-user-is-logged-in)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_user_logged_in()){// show signed in banner}else{//show another banner}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! Can you tell me how to properly insert it?

like this: <?php if (is_user_logged_in()){// show signed in banner}else{//show another banner}; ?>

Comment: This question has already been answered many times. How does your answer improve upon past answers?